# How to persist a complex object in the View while updating just a small portion

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, xml-serialization

I have a feeling this could be a basic question!

I have a complex object ie a document object which contains properties that are lists of other objects. It has been created by deserializing some XML.

I would like to pass the entire Model to the View

```
Return ViewResult(MyDoc)
```

In the View some properties are edited. Control is then returned back to the Post Controller:

```
        [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Index(Document myDoc)
```

"myDoc" now just represents my Form's fields. I suspect this is ModelBinding at work. So I guess I need to persist my complex object in a hidden field(example would be great) or as a session object. However I am a bit confused how my updated field gets merged back into the persisted object(hidden or session).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, this is model binding at work.

The binding occurs almost automatically when you use HtmlHelpers such as :

```
@Html.TextboxFor(model => model.PropertyName)
```

This line actually creates something a little bit like this :

```
<input type="textbox" id="Modelobject_PropertyName" name="ModelObject.PropertyName" />
```

Then when you submit your form, the `DefaultModelBinder` is able to deserialize the POST value and create and object of the given type (at least it will try), if it can't find a corresponding entry, the property will be null and if an entry have no corresponding property, it will be ignored (unless you have other parameters).

You can read this [article](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx) it's a little bit old, but it's still pretty accurate.

As an exemple:

Let's say you have a simple object :

```
public class IndexModel
{
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
    public bool MyCheckbox { get; set; }
}
```

A simple controler :

```
public class TestingController : Controller
{
    [OutputCache(Duration=0, NoStore = true)]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new IndexModel { MyProperty = "hi" });
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [OutputCache(Duration=0, NoStore = true)]
    public ActionResult Index(IndexModel model)
    {
        model.MyProperty += "!";
        ModelState.Clear();
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

And a simple view :

```
@model MvcApp.Models.IndexModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MyProperty)<p />
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.MyProperty) 
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MyCheckbox)<p />
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.MyCheckbox)
    </div> 

    <input type="submit" />
}
```

You will see, when you submit the form, that the model is recreated completely.

If you don't want to display the actual value of a property, but still need it persisted:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.MyProperty)
```

This will generate a hidden field that will be posted back and, therefor, persisted.

Happy coding !

Comment: Hi Lostdreamer, A most comprehensive and helpful reply. I agree this is the way I need to go and my previous comment to Pablo states. I would like to mark both answers are equally useful. Not sure if I can do this. Hug thanks again. Ed

Answer (score 5):

Is storing that large object in the view entirely necessary?

The `View` seems to have no control over that content, so you probably don't want to send all that data to the `View`. It seems you are applying a mind-set based on `ViewState`, which doesn't really fit very well with MVC, IMHO.

Communication between the `View` and the `Controller` is done through `ViewModels`, and there's usually no need to store any large serialized data and making that go back and forth when interacting with the server.

Can't you create a `ViewModel` that represents only the useful data for the view (the fields), and get that data back in your `Action` by receiving the `ViewModel` during POST, and afterwards synchronize the information you obtained from the View with what you load from your XML only at that time?

Comment: Pablo, you are correct. I have now created a View Model and this works well. I just now need to work out a good way of creating/maintaining all of the ViewModels since there will be quite a lot on the one Document Model. However I guess it will also provide me with an extra layer of validation (via annotations) and I suspect a performance advantage since one is just moving ViewModels around. However I still need to either persist the Document Model via a session or deserialize it each time I need it. But this is server based and thus more controllable than the network. Thanks. Ed

Comment: Hi Pablo, Both answers are correct for different reasons for me, but I cannot tick both. However I have marked both up. Many thanks. Ed